# Intersection of two matrices in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Is there any function or method in Julia that would allow one to compute the **intersection** of two matrices A and B?

Comment: what do you mean by intersection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible definitions for intersection.
Suppose that you have:

```
julia> a=[1 2 3;4 5 6;3 2 1]
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 3  2  1

julia> b = a'
3×3 adjoint(::Matrix{Int64}) with eltype Int64:
 1  4  3
 2  5  2
 3  6  1
```

and if you mean by intersection you mean matrix with elements who have the same values in both matrices and zero otherwise you could do:

```
julia> (a .== b) .* a
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  0  3
 0  5  0
 3  0  1
```